which channel should I install on conda?
when I try to download tensorflow with a higher version than 2.11, I get this code block and wanna know what channel I should get so I can install the version I need of tensorflow
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow=2.15*

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/sean
  - defaults
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64

Tried to ask GPT-4 but with no result so I hope someone can help. and also, I hope I got the channel and package relation correctly!

The conda-forge channel has no builds of tensorflow 2.x for Windows.  The anaconda channel (included in the "defaults" channel) does have builds for Windows, however, the most recent version is 2.10.0.
 
You can search using conda:
# this returns nothing.
conda search -c defaults -c conda-forge "tensorflow-base>=2.12"

A search with an older versions show the latest build for Windows, only in the default channel.
conda search -c defaults -c conda-forge "tensorflow-base>=2.9"

